# "out of memory" error when installing ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel, live-usb

I own a 2021 Lg Gram and have been trying to install Ubuntu on dual boot (wiht a USB drive).Every time i click "try to install ubuntu" or "Ubuntu safe graphics" i get the screen showing "error: out of memory, press to continue".
If i wait a while or click any key it shows a kernel panic screen, and i can only exit by forcing my pc to shutdown. I have searched this issue and tried many things i have found but haven't found a solution. I was hoping someone could help.

Comment: Disable TPM, SGX ( if you have that ) and Secure Boot in your UEFI.

Comment: See how I did it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421686/solved-how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-lg-gram-17-2021

Comment: Disabling TPM and SGX did not work @HomerSimpsin

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact problem.  I bough a new MSI laptop and installed 64GB of ram and I got "out of memory" when I selected the first item on the ubuntu boot menu.

I tried countless combinations of failures including what was describe in other posts on this site and other sites.

I determined that the problem is related to the boot program being a 32 bit program which allows a total of 4GB of memory space for the boot program to use.  My laptop as an i7-12800hx processor with integrated graphics and an nvidia-3070ti.

I tried the same install usb drive on a PC with no integrated video card on the CPU and it worked fine.  The PC it work on had a thread-ripper CPU with no integrated graphics and a geforce GTX 1080 pci-express graphics card.

To get the laptop to boot and install ubuntu 22.04.1, I had to go into my bios (right ctrl-shift, left alt-f2 to get to the advanced bios) and switch primary display to the PEG (PCI Express Graphics (nvidia rtx 3070ti)) and disable anything to do with the intel integrated graphics on the chip.  Then I had to hook up a monitor with a lower resolution (1680x1050 ) (through a thunderbolt docking station) to get it to work.  I tried with a 4K monitor but it did not sync up properly.  Doing all of this prevented the mapping of shared memory to the graphics controller into the lower 4GB of ram.

After I did all of that, the installation worked.  I could boot from the USB boot menu and install ubuntu 22.04.  After the installation was complete, I had to switch my graphics back to normal in the bios.

This fix worked great for me.  The installation was basically flawless and it did not involve creating new ramfs file systems or modifying grub.  No software changes at all. It was simply disabling the integrated graphics in my bios for the install.

By the way, after about 30 failed attempts, I went and installed fedora 36 to see if it was related to ubuntu. Fedora installed fine the first time.  I just could not get the drivers that I needed to use nvenc in ffmpeg and still have the system boot after loading drivers.  It failed so I went back to trying to find the solution using ubuntu.

Also, I did leave the secure-boot disabled from one of my many earlier attempts.  You will probably need to disable secure-boot functionality in your bios also.  (See other posts on this topic for that)

I hope this post helps you solve your installation problem.

dave hansen

Comment: FWIW I was able to get it working on a ThinkCenter desktop by changing the initial and max memory allocation for integrated graphics to the lowest values. Initial 32MB and max 128MB. After that I was able to boot into the installer no problem. But I only thought about that after reading this post, so thanks!

Comment: same problem on macbook pro 2014..got ubuntu to boot by holding down option key during boot, select efi device, select Advanced Options for Ubuntu, boot into OS, then disabled swap: sudo swapoff -a, fallocate -l 8G /swapfile, chmod 600 /swapfile, and confirmed my swap file was entered into /etc/fstab. Rebooted into Ubuntu 22.04 with no further issues. hint from: https://www.techsupportpk.com/2017/11/resolve-out-of-memory-errors-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, setting Max TOLUD (lg gram, In Bios advanced settings ctrl + shift + alt +f7 ->  Advanced -> Intel Advanced Menu -> Memory Configuration -> Max TOLUD) to more than 1GB helped me.

hint from : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1842320/comments/94

Comment: Worked on a MSI GT77 Titan (12USG-009).  Set TOLUD from dynamic to 1.25 GB and it booted fine.

Comment: That helped me as well

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with Ubuntu 22.04.

See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1970402

In the ticket you'll notice there is a commenter who has an LG Gram laptop.

The ticket is set with `milestone` to `ubuntu-22.04.1`, so hopefully it gets fixed soon.

For now you can install Ubuntu 21.10 instead.

Comment: It's still broken :(

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue, that was when I tried using dd to make a bootable disk for ubuntu 22.04. I ended up using [rufus](https://rufus.ie) to make the bootable disk and it worked. I am typing this from my instance

Comment: Thank you, using Rufus (with the recommended usb copy option) worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Create your live USB using "Startup Disk Creator" on another Linux system.
2. First enter Windows and disable "Fast Startup" in the preferences.
3. It is preferable to repartition the hard drive at this time using the Windows Disk Management tool, reducing the Windows partition size and creating the Ubuntu partition/s (this might be the reason you got an out of memory error, if you hadn't done this step).
4. Exit, shut down Windows, insert the live USB and reboot into the BIOS / UEFI.
5. Disable "Secure Boot" and make sure the UEFI / BIOS is set to UEFI and **not** Legacy.
6. Set the boot priority to boot from the Live USB.
7. Exit UEFI / BIOS (usually F12) and it should boot into the live session.

Please report back if this works.

[How to guide dual boot](https://www.itechguides.com/dual-boot-ubuntu-windows-10/)

[Older article, still pertinent](https://www.pcsteps.com/3305-prepare-windows-dual-boot-installation/#Prepare_Windows_81_Windows_10)